# NodeJS & MongoDB Canonicalize query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Having the following doc:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cdc08d8cd0baf815c4be240"),
    "id" : "9301870",
    "titles" : {
        "en_US" : "en",
        "de_de" : "de"
    }
}
```

The following query:

```
db.getCollection('table').find({id:"9301870"},{titles:{en_US:1}})
```

Return the following error:

```
Error: error: {
    "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Unsupported projection option: titles: { en_US: 1.0 }",
    "code" : 17287
}
```

What do i missing here?

P.S the document has much more complex data structure - but I would like to  be able to return only the relevant lang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/index.html#query-on-nested-field) instead of nested object, try:

```
db.getCollection('table').find({id:"9301870"},{ "titles.en_US":1})
```